# Getting Black keys in iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios

Some users of our app are reporting that sometimes they are seeing black letters in their iOS keyboard while using our App.

See screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of iOS keyboard showing black letters]

Has anyone seen this problem before? I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: This clearly is an iOS bug.

Comment: do they use a custom keyboard when this happens

Comment: then it could be an iOS bug OR that keyboard's fault

Comment: No custom keyboard, default keyboard